# Cordova Device orientation depending if is tablet or not

Tags: iphone, cordova, ipad, mobile

I know that you can use the config.xml file to set the device orientation to either landscape or portrait. What I would like to do is set it to Portrait for phone (e.g. iPhone, samsung s4, ...) and landscape to tablet (iPad, etc.)

Any idea on how I can do this ?

Comment: There is a plugin for that ;-))  https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-istablet

Comment: That plugin seems to tell you in app. How would you then go on to lock the screen orientation in app?

All I found so far is:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation
And I am not so sure how compatible this is with iOS and Android browsers.

Comment: For a lock take this: https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation